# Где найти подробный гайд по Instagram Direct API?

Tags: instagram-api, doc

прошу помочь мне найти адекватную документацию для подключения и взаимодействия через открытое API instagram direct

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/products/messenger/messenger-api-instagram/

Comment: Та же проблема, Удалось что то найти?